# Slicing the text in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

pandas `dataframe`:

[image]

In the screenshot, I got a pandas `dataframe`.
I want to insert a column name with 'City' and add city name form slicing the name from 'Purchase Order' column.

I tried, and not getting idea, how to slice?

please complete the code with the following

```
all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].str[]
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Provide your code and attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select second lists by indexing:

```
all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].str.split(', ').str[1]
```

Or select second column:

```
all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].str.split(', ', expand=True)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Series.str.split` and use `str` accesors for indexing:

```
all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].str.split(', ').str[1]
```

Or you could try with `str.extract`:

```
all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].str.extract(', (\w+), ')
```

Comment: Wait... Why does your and @Jezrael 's answer look exactly same?

Comment: @Sujay We answered in the same time, he was maybe few secs faster, anyway I added another solution with `str.extract`.

Comment: That is better! Now 2 different solutions.

Comment: Ya, now easy check - it is `21 seconds` difference - 42:21 vs 42:00

Comment: @jezrael Oh yeah, anyway I had another solution as well